# Problems adding new domain to httpd.conf file

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, httpd, httpd.conf

So, I just bought a brand new domain. I set up my dns records with the host (godaddy) but something strange happens on my server.

I've added this to the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.newdomainname.tld
DocumentRoot /usr/share/roundcube/
</VirtualHost>
```

But somehow I'm redirected to the root of my server.
Then I tried adding this under the entry for the new domain name:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName shop.olddomainname.tld
DocumentRoot /usr/share/roundcube/
</VirtualHost>
```

And it worked without any problems.
What's going on? Am I forgetting anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is your first additional domain, do you have a NameVirtualHost outside of the VirtualHosts section?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

The setup for multi VirtualHosts is documented nicely at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

A good way to figure out what you have configured is to run

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S
```

Which will return all directives currently configured.

Comment: I had that in the ports.conf file, but not in the httpd.conf file. I also have a few files in sites-enabled/, but don't really know what files get loaded at what time...

Comment: Okay, you can figure out what the VirtualHost setting are by running httpd -S (added to original answer).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you should define your virtual hosts in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.  These get linked to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` by the `a2ensite` command.

You may want to examine the existing default site and possibly disable it with the `a2dissite` command.  The first defined site will be treated as the default site by apache.
As your definitions are the same, you may just want one site with a serveralias defined.